# Using loop to create the new variable from the ratio of the existing variable in the data-frame

Tags: r, loops

I have recently learning loop and would like to apply it to my data analysis. I would like to use loop to create two new columns from the existing data frame:

Assum this is my dataframe

```
var1<- c(10, 12, 15, 34)
var2<- c(11, 17, 26, 45) 
var3<- c(14, 16, 46, 78)

df<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
```

I woul like to write a loop to create the two new columns which are the ratio of var4= var1/var2 and var5= va2/var3.

## Write a for loop

```
df$var4= ""  # create empty column
df$var5=""   # create empty column

for (i in df) {
  var4= df$var1 / df$var2
  var5= df$var2 / df$var3
df.final= as.data.frame(df, var4, var5)
}
```

##Code not work at all.

Can anyone suggest how I can use loop in here. I would like to stick to loop not sth else. Hope you can guide

Kind Regards,

synat

Comment: Well,  `df$var4 <- df$var1 / df$var2` and `df$var5 <- df$var2 / df$var3` works without loop. By applying loop you are just repeating the same thing multiple times and still getting the same result.

Comment: Hi Ronak, yep, make sense. you know how many times does the loop repeat I write code that way? I have no idea !! I am trying to learn loop and function and just try it wherever possible in my data analysis so I can be better at it. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traverse the rows of a data frame in R, you need to change the for loop in your code.
Instead of `i in df` it should be `i in 1:nrow(df)`.
The code will look like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$var4 = df$var1 / df$var2
  df$var5 = df$var2 / df$var3
}

df.final <- df[c("var4", "var5")]
df.final
```

The output will look like this:

```
      var4      var5
1 0.9090909 0.7857143
2 0.7058824 1.0625000
3 0.5769231 0.5652174
4 0.7555556 0.5769231
```

**EDIT:** As Limey has suggested, there is no need for a `for loop` to achieve this result as it is redundant to do so. One can simply do this using following:

```
df$var4 <- df$var1 / df$var2
df$var5 <- df$var2 / df$var3
```

It will give you the same result.

Comment: This is *NOT* a good answer.  Compare the results of this "solution" with that of simply `df$var4 = df$var1 / df$var2; df$var5 = df$var2 / df$var3`.  They are identical.  The loop simply overwrites the solution nrow(df)-1 times.  R is vectorised.  There is absolutely no need to write a loop to accomplish this, unless the intention is to loop over *columns* rather than *rows*.  And then there are other ways of doing this.  As per @RonakShah's comment above.

Comment: I get your point @Limey, that there are more easy and efficient ways of doing this. But, it the question it is clearly mentioned that they want to do it using `for loop` only.